# How to built osip (C library) for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, static-libraries

I am trying to build Osip (http://www.gnu.org/software/osip/) for iOS. I don't find any good source in the web which explains how I can use a C library (compile it etc.) and include it into my project.

If you know a good source, please post it here.

... an example how things can be done with XCode would be awesome :)

Regards